# Jpgfdraw and transparency problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, transparency

I have built dozens of shapes with [jpgfdraw](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/) . The problem I have is problems with the transparency of shapes. Why this happens? is there a solution?

I take this as an output in pdf after I've done compiling via xelatex. From jpgfdraw I have saved by selecting export to pgf environment *.tex and with `\input` I entering to the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{1.5}{\input{figure.test.tex}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

here is what I see on screen of jpgfdraw

[image]

The jpgfdraw file is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxaG1GVbo3S5XzFBOXBPbnpMT0k)

Here I quote the code that outputs from jpgfdraw

```
% Created by Jpgfdraw version 0.5.6b
% 12 Νοε 2012 12:56:12 μμ
\begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{0bp}{240.934967bp}{116.117359bp}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.499999bp}{105.474924bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.499999bp}{115.617361bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{240.434981bp}{115.617361bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{240.434981bp}{105.474924bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.499999bp}{105.474924bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{jdrlinear0}{100bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.501961,0.501961,0.501961); rgb(32.5bp)=(0.501961,0.501961,0.501961); rgb(67.5bp)=(1.0,1.0,1.0); rgb(100bp)=(1.0,1.0,1.0)}
\pgfshadepath{jdrlinear0}{0.0}\pgfseteorule
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2.198393bp}{105.003796bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{238.782056bp}{105.003796bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{115.952344bp}{52.759458bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{115.952344bp}{38.859201bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{38.859201bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{52.759458bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{115.952344bp}{52.759458bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}\pgfseteorule\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{115.952344bp}{52.759458bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{115.952344bp}{38.859201bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{38.859201bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{52.759458bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{115.952344bp}{52.759458bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{53.025916bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{51.456197bp}}{\pgfpoint{128.106454bp}{50.183691bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.782164bp}{50.183691bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{119.457874bp}{50.183691bp}}{\pgfpoint{115.952342bp}{51.456197bp}}{\pgfpoint{115.952342bp}{53.025916bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{115.952342bp}{54.595636bp}}{\pgfpoint{119.457874bp}{55.868142bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.782164bp}{55.868142bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{128.106454bp}{55.868142bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{54.595636bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{53.025916bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}\pgfseteorule\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{53.025916bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{51.456197bp}}{\pgfpoint{128.106454bp}{50.183691bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.782164bp}{50.183691bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{119.457874bp}{50.183691bp}}{\pgfpoint{115.952342bp}{51.456197bp}}{\pgfpoint{115.952342bp}{53.025916bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{115.952342bp}{54.595636bp}}{\pgfpoint{119.457874bp}{55.868142bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.782164bp}{55.868142bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{128.106454bp}{55.868142bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{54.595636bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.611987bp}{53.025916bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{116.053072bp}{52.309634bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{116.053072bp}{50.178731bp}}{\pgfpoint{116.053072bp}{40.948162bp}}{\pgfpoint{116.053072bp}{38.817259bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{118.055865bp}{35.483023bp}}{\pgfpoint{130.072624bp}{35.833995bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.522922bp}{38.817259bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{131.522922bp}{41.123648bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.522922bp}{50.04837bp}}{\pgfpoint{131.522922bp}{52.279551bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{129.133383bp}{49.471773bp}}{\pgfpoint{118.707809bp}{49.166928bp}}{\pgfpoint{116.053072bp}{52.309634bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{jdrlinear1}{100bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.25098,0.25098,0.25098); rgb(32.5bp)=(0.25098,0.25098,0.25098); rgb(67.5bp)=(0.74902,0.74902,0.74902); rgb(100bp)=(0.74902,0.74902,0.74902)}
\pgfshadepath{jdrlinear1}{-45.0}\pgfseteorule\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{125.131925bp}{53.684004bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{125.131925bp}{53.007114bp}}{\pgfpoint{124.552712bp}{52.458385bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.83822bp}{52.458385bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{123.123723bp}{52.458385bp}}{\pgfpoint{122.544511bp}{53.007114bp}}{\pgfpoint{122.544511bp}{53.684004bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{122.544511bp}{54.360893bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.123723bp}{54.90962bp}}{\pgfpoint{123.83822bp}{54.90962bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{124.552712bp}{54.90962bp}}{\pgfpoint{125.131925bp}{54.360893bp}}{\pgfpoint{125.131925bp}{53.684004bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgftransformcm{1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{1.0}{\pgfpoint{118.968893bp}{42.151974bp}}
\pgftext[left,base]{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape\normalsize
\color[rgb]{1.0,1.0,1.0}$m$}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{2.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{91.114628bp}{1.546696bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{91.028801bp}{9.247424bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.171104bp}{12.505424bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.192561bp}{8.791759bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{85.149647bp}{5.214794bp}}{\pgfpoint{98.034769bp}{12.157206bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.165435bp}{16.310221bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{98.117579bp}{20.319223bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.289116bp}{27.268948bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.321302bp}{23.555284bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{85.289116bp}{19.841619bp}}{\pgfpoint{98.243302bp}{26.881633bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.165435bp}{30.663647bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{98.350586bp}{34.582361bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.256931bp}{42.260305bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.192561bp}{38.318808bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{85.256931bp}{34.240612bp}}{\pgfpoint{98.056226bp}{41.327037bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.229805bp}{45.563871bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{98.350586bp}{49.368668bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.26766bp}{56.841564bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.256931bp}{53.082333bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{85.246203bp}{49.323102bp}}{\pgfpoint{98.149764bp}{56.659298bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.165435bp}{60.464095bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{98.254031bp}{64.549604bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.289116bp}{71.286123bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.256931bp}{67.435759bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{85.224746bp}{63.995494bp}}{\pgfpoint{98.254031bp}{70.526964bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.165435bp}{74.407424bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{98.149764bp}{78.287884bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.299845bp}{85.981298bp}}{\pgfpoint{85.256931bp}{82.062584bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{85.278388bp}{78.28057bp}}{\pgfpoint{91.178998bp}{82.837214bp}}{\pgfpoint{91.243368bp}{90.127843bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{2.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{90.533093bp}{1.011076bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{90.447266bp}{8.711804bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.58957bp}{11.969803bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.611026bp}{8.256139bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{84.568113bp}{4.679174bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.453235bp}{11.621586bp}}{\pgfpoint{96.583901bp}{15.774601bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{97.536045bp}{19.783603bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.707582bp}{26.733328bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.739767bp}{23.019664bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{84.707582bp}{19.305999bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.661768bp}{26.346013bp}}{\pgfpoint{96.583901bp}{30.128027bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{97.769052bp}{34.046741bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.675397bp}{41.724685bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.611026bp}{37.783188bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{84.675397bp}{33.704992bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.474692bp}{40.791417bp}}{\pgfpoint{96.648271bp}{45.028251bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{97.769052bp}{48.833048bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.686125bp}{56.305943bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.675397bp}{52.546713bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{84.664668bp}{48.787482bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.56823bp}{56.123678bp}}{\pgfpoint{96.583901bp}{59.928475bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{97.672496bp}{64.013984bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.707582bp}{70.750503bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.675397bp}{66.900139bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{84.643212bp}{63.459873bp}}{\pgfpoint{97.672496bp}{69.991343bp}}{\pgfpoint{96.583901bp}{73.871803bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{97.56823bp}{77.752263bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.71831bp}{85.445678bp}}{\pgfpoint{84.675397bp}{81.526964bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{84.696854bp}{77.74495bp}}{\pgfpoint{90.597464bp}{82.301594bp}}{\pgfpoint{90.661834bp}{89.592223bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\end{pgfpicture}
```

Comment: That's odd. Do you have any `\pgfsetstrokeopacity` or `\pgfsetfillopacity` commands in the exported .tex file?

Comment: Yes, there is a `\pgfsetstrokeopacity` but not `\pgfsetfillopacity`

Comment: Do you have any transparent fill paint or is it just transparent line paint in your image?

Comment: I have transparent fill paint. Ιn a minute Ι will  upload the jpgfdraw file and the code.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I know that the library `\tikzlibrary`does not work with the version 2009 TexLive that I use, probably this have something to do and may have extensions and elsewhere? maybe entirely irrelevant what I say

Comment: I think the export's gone wrong if it's not writing the fill opacity to the .tex file. Can you write this code to an ajr file and try exporting it:
    `AJR 1.4
    0
    G 1 P T Y 0 0.5 1.0 0 2 0 10 0 0 0 0
    C 4 100 70 L 100 150 L 200 150
    L 200 70 L 100 70 0 0 0 0`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes certainly do, but I do not understand which is the ajr file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6402/discussion-between-nicola-talbot-and-karathan)

Comment: The problem is the gradient paint. I don't know how to add transparency to commands like `\pgfdeclareverticalshading`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Do you know if it is possible to open a *.jdr file with another program and get output in a format that supports the gradient shading?